# Wubi 11.10 freezes during installation

Tags: installation, 11.10, wubi, freeze

Wubi freezes when it's almost done copying files. The cursor still has the spinning animation, but everything becomes unresponsive to mouse clicks. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: I was having the same problem. I wasn't connect to the internet but when I did the problem went away.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

On menu of boot up press F6. Check one or all of them. See what works for you. I was able to install after this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you no longer have this problem, but I had it too and fixed it by using those command lines:

```
libata.force=noncq
libata.force=noacpi
libata.force=nomodeset
```

I also downloaded the 64bit Version (was using the 32 before), and removed my Wireless Network Adapter (though this propably did nothing).

Answer (score 0):

Check MD5 and SHA1, i think you are using windows. You can use HashTab on Win & Mac. Here is download page. http://implbits.com/HashTab.aspx

Comment: Well the md5sum is correct, so I doubt that the iso has any problems.

Comment: Please describe more info - computer brand/model, specs. Where is it freezing exactly? Generally it's better to give more descriptive information so we can understand where it's failing.